# Why Global Mapper's georeferencer misplaces controlpoint?

Tags: georeferencing, global-mapper

I am sometimes met with the problem that Global Mapper (v17.0) georeferencer misplaces controlpoints I am trying to use, but adding and then deleting the controlpoint solved the issue. However currently I can not overcome this problem as it's now alaways does this:

[image]

Does anybody know a solution to this or what is the cause of it?

Comment: Maybe you have vector layer behind this raster.